# No Launcher Activity Found Error?

Tags: android

My application was running without error but I don't know why all of a sudden it is showing this error:-

> No Launcher activity found!
>
> The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

I have search and found many link and question on stack overflow but unable to solve it:-
Here is my manyfest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.flashdeal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<!-- All Required Permissions Are Start Here -->
<permission
    android:name="com.flashdeal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.flashdeal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AppSplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="AppSplashScreen" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.autocomplete.SearchLocation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AppLoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FollowerUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserHistory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FollowingUsers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.map.DealLocationOnMap"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SeeUserDetail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.map.MapGroupData"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LikeUserScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowOtherUserDeal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DealDetailPage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseBusiness"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutApp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AppMenuScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyFavouriteList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseDealLocation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.mycamera.CaptureDealImage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateDeal"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >

            <!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QRCodeWebView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.mycamera.SetDealImageCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Twitt"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.twitter.Twitt"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.flashdeal.twitter.Twitt2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainTabActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MoreOptionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".showDealsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TempActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditIndividualProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.flashdeal.qrcode.Options" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.flashdeal.qrcode.QRScanner" >
        </activity>
        <!-- GCM BroadCastReciever start -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.flashdeal" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- GCM BroadCastReciever End -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</uses-permission>
```

anyone guide me where I am wrong because app showing this error before some time.

Comment: remove meta data of Launcher Activity and try..

Comment: no error log showing related to this

Comment: @Sadeshkumar Periyasamy I have remove already this,but giviing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not properly closed uses-permission tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
....
....
....
<!-- GCM BroadCastReciever End -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    **</application>
</uses-permission>**
```

That was closed at end of the page. remove that it will work

Answer (score 1):

Check your package structure when giving value for `android:name` in *activity* tag.

**For example :**

If your package structure  `com.xxx.yy.app` is like this and all your activities reside in app folder then you can give `android:name=".yourActivityName"` in *activity* tag.

If app folder has a subfolder and some `Activities` reside in that subfolder then you can give `android:name=".subfoldername.yourActivityName"` in *activity* tag.

Answer (score 0):

My Issue will be resolve when I copy manifest from my project backup but I couldn't know why did occure this issue..